# How do I keep my li height from changing in IE8 when I use jQuery sortable and start dragging

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable to sort `<li>` tags. It works perfectly using Firefox, but the `<li>` height changes when dragged within IE8. I have added the following CSS statements but they do not help:

```
height: auto !important; /* Firefox,
Safari, IE8, etc */ height: 110px; /*
IE6 */ min-height:110px; /* Firefox,
Safari, IE8, etc */
```

You can test it out over at [ColorCombos.com/ComboMaker.html](http://colorcombos.com/combomaker.html)

Answer (score 0):

Give line-height a try. I use that a lot when setting the height for li menu items, to work across FF, IE, and Chrome.

Comment: Good idea. I took the height off of the li item level and added line-height to the ul. After that change, the li items shrunk down in IE8. (But they stopped changing shape when dragging.) So, it looked like IE8 was not recognizing the line. So I added a break and a non breakable space behind everything and the li height corrected. Now... it looks like the li width reduces slightly upon drag in IE8. I'll have to live with that. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can fix it, but i dont think its that big of a problem so i would not worry about it.

Comment: what? What kind of suggestion is that? He wouldn't post it here if it isn't a problem. Of course it's a problem. Downvoted.